# possible way to reduce the number of clicks to get to what I need

Tags: google-analytics

It takes me many mouse clicks (and the wait time inbetween to get what I want to click next Google Analytics for a given country, then more clicks for cities within countries.

I've looked at their custom reporting tab, and I must admit I find it quite confusing. Twice I've tried to use it to get what I want, and I failed both times.

Now, if I have to keep trying and trying to get what I want, so be it. However, before expending that kind of time, I'm hoping that someone here can tell me: yes, that can be done, or no, you really can't do it.

What I do each time is:

3 clicks to get the date. I'm only interested in seeing data for the immediately previous day.

Then click on the first country (an eventually down the country list).

Then click on the first city of the country (and eventually down the city list).

Then click on Content.

Then click on Pages.

Then click on Page Title.

So, is the Custom Reporting the way to go or is there another way?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give. It will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, custom reporting could set that up for you every time, but when you've drilled down, could you schedule that report to you via email? Might be a faster/easier way.

Comment: I have to admit I hadn't thought of having it emailed, but I'm encouraged that custom reporting can do give me what I need in a more expeditious manner, and I'll certainly be looking into the emailing.